# Create observables from a dynamic array

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have something like this currently

```
onValueChange() {
  let someObj = //dynamically created
  this.processUsers(someObj);
}

processUsers(someObj) {
  from(Object.keys(someObj))
    .pipe(
      concatMap(key => this.getUsers(key)
    )
    .subscribe(res => ...)
}
```

onValueChange is a method called when something in a form changes and this triggers the method `processUsers` with an obj that was constructed when `onValueChange` is called.
`processUsers` then uses this obj to do some async tasks.

This works OK if there is a single trigger but if when processUsers is called consecutively with different objects, the async tasks gets messed up.

So, how can I use rxjs to complete `processUsers` to be done with the current obj before taking in the next? My first thought is to use an array that I would push `someObj` into and `processUsers` should subscribe to the array but I'm not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to handle all your invocations of `onValueChange` in a single stream.  In this case, you could use a `Subject` to push your objects through.  This allows you to subscribe to a single observable to process your items:

```
private obj$ = new Subject();

onValueChange() {
  let someObj = ...
  this.obj$.next(someObj);
}

private processUsersSub = this.obj$.pipe(
  switchMap(obj => this.processUsers(obj)) // depending on desired behavior you could
).subscribe();                             // use mergeMap, exhaustMap, concatMap

private processUsers(someObj) {
  return from(Object.keys(someObj)).pipe(
    concatMap(key => this.getUsers(key)
  );
}
```

Depending on the behavior you want when a new emissions of `obj$` occurs before the previous one is completed, you can choose the appropriate operator:

- `switchMap` - switch to new source and discard any remaining processing
- `exhaustMap` - discard any new emissions that occur while processing is in progress
- `concatMap` - continue processing old items until complete, then process new items
- `mergeMap` - process all items old and new, all at the same time (*can specify concurrency limit*)

Comment: Thank you! this works for me, but I was wondering why `processUsersSub` assignment is being done here.